# You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

We are trying to upload a new APK to submit a new version of our app on Google Play Store, but we are getting the following error:

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate.

```
The upload certificate has fingerprint:
SHA1: 2A:38:91:08:99:54:25:72:EB:CE:6A:14:39:71:B0:42:FE:D0:01:55

and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: DF:57:90:5C:AD:3F:E5:53:C4:98:9D:4A:93:DE:0F:80:5A:18:AB:99
```

You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 2021032501.

How can we solve this if we don't have contact to the previous developers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same certificate with previous versions of your application, and the APK of the new version must also have the same package name as previous versions.

If you lost the certificate you used in the previous versions you will have to communicate with google support ([here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?_ga=2.208512148.780324896.1619810442-2102842394.1619810442&_gac=1.89519209.1619810442.Cj0KCQjw1a6EBhC0ARIsAOiTkrHNUrYU-5jLZIJyTV6lXh-EdBETZBLbVVXamskRdNlaohzXtEMyl7EaAr31EALw_wcB#topic=3450769)) and follow the steps they will tell you to recreate this file

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don’t know why but every time we try to generate a new certificate key it’s always generating the same one. We have followed all the instructions from google team but it’s not generating a different key. Do you know why? Thx.

Comment: We lost the certificate from the previous version and now when we try to generate the PEM file it’s generating always the same one and google it’s not accepting.

Comment: @Intelligent Web Crew This problem is for another question, please make a new post with this problem and If I can I will help you 

Comment: I just created a new post for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385031/generate-and-register-a-new-upload-key-android-react-native

Comment: Hi @gsepetadelis, we are trying to generate a new PEM file and APK with the same SHA1 fingerprint, but for some reason the APK is not changing the SHA1 fingerprint. Do you know why? Thanks!